# How to check duplicate element in 2 arrays with a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create a function that can check if 2 arrays are subsets or not, and if yes return true else return false

For example if :
x = ["BOB","ADA","KEN"]
y = ["KEN", "BOB"]
return true

x = ["BOB","ADA","KEN"]
y = ["KEN", "BOB" , "DAN"]
return false

Any suggestions on how to create this function?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the second array by the first to see if there's anything left afterwards. If so, they don't overlap.

```js
const hasOverlap = (arr1, arr2) => arr2.filter(a => !arr1.includes(a)).length === 0

let x = ["BOB","ADA","KEN"], y = ["KEN", "BOB" ] 
console.log(hasOverlap(x,y))

x = ["BOB","ADA","KEN"]
y = ["KEN", "BOB", "JOE"] 
console.log(hasOverlap(x,y))
```

Comment: Thanks! How about if I want to write a function that takes two arrays as input to do this ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, this is taking 2 arrays as input. Can you update your question with what you mean + expected result?